# MySQL join query for more than 1 id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

So i encountered this problem when I was specifying a query for 2 connected tables with more than 1 id.

Suppose there are 2 tables:

Table **Competition**

- p1_id(varchar)(FK)
- p2_id(varchar)(FK)
- p3_id(varchar)(FK)

table **Competition** refers to table **Player** by the *player.id*

Table **Player**

- id (PK)
- name
- level
- gender

The problem is **I want to retrieve the `p1 name`, `p2 name` and `p3 name`** from table **Competition**...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

join the table player `thrice` to get it's equivalent values,

```
SELECT  a.*,
        b.name Player1_Name,
        c.name Player2_Name,
        d.name Player3_Name
FROM    Competition a   
        INNER JOIN player b
            a.p1_ID = b.ID
        INNER JOIN player c
            a.p2_ID = c.ID
        INNER JOIN player d
            a.p3_ID = d.ID
```

If one of the columns in table `competition` is *nullable*, better use `LEFT JOIN` than `INNER JOIN`.

To fully gain knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)